# How can I extend my code do divide by a 64bit integer? (128bit / 64bit)

Tags: c++, c, division

My problem is that my Code just divides the 128bit by a 32bit integer but not by a 64bit.
I know there are some instructions like _umul128() or __uint128_t for this, but I need a portable version.

The code only work when the divisor is smaller than a uint32_t and I don`t know why.

```
uint64_t udiv32(uint64_t high, uint64_t low, uint32_t divisor, uint32_t* rem)
{
    uint64_t q0, r0;
    uint64_t q1, r1;
    uint64_t temp;

    const uint32_t a_lo = low & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    const uint32_t a_hi = low >> 32;

    r0 = high % divisor;

    temp = ((r0 << 32) | a_hi);
    q1 = temp / divisor;
    r1 = temp % divisor;

    temp = ((r1 << 32) | a_lo);
    q0 = temp / divisor;
    r0 = temp % divisor;

    *rem = r0;
    return ((q1 << 32) | q0);
}
```

Maybe someone can help me to extend the function so that the divisor can be a uint64_t.
Also pls no hate im new to this :)

Comment: Are you asking for C++ or "C"? You need to choose one, because they are different languages with possibly different solutions (or at least prefered solutions). And may I ask why divisor is an uint32_t and not a uint64_t?

Comment: The particular code you present declares `divisor` as a `uint32_t`.  *Of course* that function will not produce the arithmetic result when the divisor argument is too wide to be represented as a `uint32_t`.

Comment: But with that said, yes, it looks like the function is specific to the 128-bit / 32-bit case.

Comment: The shown code is not C. Don't spam C tag subscribers with a C++ code.

Comment: What makes you say it's not C, @273K?

Comment: Yeah? Im sorry but this is vaild C code.

Comment: I use 'uint32_t' because if I switch to 'uint64_t' it won`t work, like I said. I just want to extend the function so I can change the type to 'uint64_t' and it will still work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `0xFFFF'FFFF`

Comment: Okay sorry, but it works on MSVC, I didn't know that it doens't work on gcc. Also its not that the code has classes or something.

Comment: You don't ask about behavior differences of C and C++, thus you should not mix these tags. Don't you fill that you are not right since we don't discuss your subject here, but  its quality?

Comment: Like I said, this is my first post on this website and I know that it may not be good. Sorry but its like everyone said TOXIC af.

Comment: bro is complaining about 0xFFFF'FFFF and that the number has a little ' in it that he can just remove with one keystroke.

Comment: Tag [tag:c]: *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.*

Comment: Why all arguments do not use same integer type `uint64_t`? What should happen in case of overflow?

Comment: @273K, `0xFFFF'FFFF` is a valid C integer constant since C23.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not **is** but **will be** in 2024.

Comment: Side note: the `uint64_t` return value is not wide enough to accommodate all possible quotients.  Inasmuch as the divisor could be as small as 1, the quotient can be as wide as the dividend.  And even if the divisor is `UINT32_MAX`, there are many possible dividends for which the quotient would not fit in a `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function presented appears to implement the long division algorithm in base 2<sup>32</sup>, for the specific case of a dividend with up to four (big) digits and a one-(big-)digit divisor.  It will not handle divisors larger than 2<sup>32</sup>-1 even if you give the `divisor` parameter a wider type.

> How can I extend my code do divide by a 64bit integer?

Your best alternative would probably be two write a separate version specific to the 128-bit / 64-bit case.  You could do that in base 2<sup>64</sup>, making it simpler than the 128-bit / 32-bit version.  There is no good way to reuse the existing code itself for the purpose, though you could look to it for inspiration.  This is not a coding service, however, so I leave the details to you.